# HTML changing width in the side panels

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating side panels and this is working fine in the fixed pixel and i need to adjust the side panels according to the pixel. This is the [code](http://jsfiddle.net/7jz61LLj/1/). Right now the pixel between two panels is 1024 px and it works fine for pages if the width is 1024px but i want panels to be adjusted according to the content pixel. Suppose if my pixel is not 1024px but 512px then side panels should come closer to each other and that while content between panels should be changed from 1024px to 512px. This is not my code but one of the developer who left the company wrote this and i have never done front end projects so i am not very good in handling css. I tried to fix this but i am not able to find where the content size is changing. Help would be appreciated thanks.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="ad" class="collapsed">
        <div id="banner"></div>
        <div id="expansion">

            <div id="left_panel" class="side_panel" onclick="javascript:handleClickthroughButtonClick()"></div>
            <div id="right_panel" class="side_panel" onclick="javascript:handleClickthroughButtonClick()"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about changing **.side_panel** in css

`position: absolute;`
to be

```
position: fixed;
```

So the element is positioned relative to the browser window

Comment: no the thing is that content between side panels can be 250px to 1024px and if if is 250px then sidepanels white space should be 250px.

Comment: how about change from px to % for example : width:20%;